# How to automatically approve pre-deployment approval Azure DevOps using PowerShell?

Tags: azure-devops, tfs, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to automate the Release deployment using Rest API. Below are the steps:

1. Get the latest release.
2. Deploy particular stage using API.
3. Automatically approve pre-deployment approvals.

So I am stuck at step 3, is there a way to bypass or automatically approve this using API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Approvals - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/approvals/update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) Rest API. first you need to get all the approvals (for the `id`) with [Approvals - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/approvals/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0), filter the approval by release id and then approve it.

For example:

```
$approvalsUrl = "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{org}/{project}/_apis/release/approvals?api-version=6.0"

$token = "PAT"
$script:Base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $User, $token)))
$header = @{Authorization = ("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $approvalsUrl -Method Get -Headers $header
$latestReleaseId = 1111
$id = $response.value.Where({ $_.release.id -eq $latestReleaseId }).id
# approve 

$body = '{
  "status": "approved",
  "comments": "Good to go"
}'

$approvalUrl = "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{org}/{project}/_apis/release/approvals/$($id)?api-version=6.0"

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $approvalUrl -Method Patch -Headers $header -Body $body -ContentType application/json
```

Comment: I have tried this API but getting `The current user is not authorized to update the release stage step status` do you know what sort of permission is missing.

Comment: maybe `Manage release approvers`?

Comment: Thanks @Shayki I have resolved, one way is to add that `user in approval group` and secondly give `Manage release approvers` permission in release security setting.